# How to display the value of state in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional counter app I'm working on with react-redux. I can see every time that I dispatch an action using my Increment/Decrement functions the state updates, however, I am unable to actually output the value of my state.

This is my first time trying to build a redux application with modules(as opposed to building an html file with a redux cdn). Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
//App.js

import { Increment, Decrement } from './redux'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.props.count}</h1> //Doesn't output anything
        <button onClick={this.props.Increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.Decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    count: state.count
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    Increment,
    Decrement
}

const AppContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

export default AppContainer
```

```
//redux.js 

import { createStore } from 'redux';

export const Increment = () => {
    return {
        type: 'INCREMENT'
    }
}

export const Decrement = () => {
    return {
        type: 'DECREMENT'
    }
}


export const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
        return state + 1

        case 'DECREMENT':
        return state - 1

        default:
        return state
    }
}


export function configureStore(intitalState = 0){
    const store = createStore(reducer, intitalState)
    return store;
}

export const store = configureStore()
```

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux';
import AppContainer from './App';

ReactDOM.render
(<Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer/>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging your state in `mapStateToProps`? I see you call `state.count` but `count` is not the name of one of your reducers. So your value is stored as the `state` itself. However, try logging the state to see if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `state` is actually a value, not an object that stores value as `count` property.

It should be either:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    count: state
})
```

Or `combineReducers` can be used to map specific reducer as store property:

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({count: reducer }), intitalState)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely missing this.